# Delete all the bot's messages in a channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to create a command in my bot that will delete all the bot's messages only. Is there a way to iterate through all the channel's messages and if it is a message the bot sent, the bot would delete it? I've understood `delete_message` but I can't figure out how to iterate through all the channel's messages, if that is even possible.
The following code wouldn't iterate through all the channel's messages, but it would delete the message if the author ID is `383804325077581834`:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == '383804325077581834':
        await bot.delete_message(message)
```

`383804325077581834` is my bot's ID. So I would like to know how I can iterate through all channel messages and delete those that were sent by my bot. Thank you so much!

**EDIT**: Tried doing this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def delete(ctx, number):
    msgs = []
    number = int(number)
    async for msg in bot.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit=number):
        if msg.author.id == '383804325077581834':
            msgs.append(msg)
        await bot.delete_messages(msgs)
```

But I get the error `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: number is a required argument that is missing.`

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def delete(ctx):
    msgs = []
    async for msg in bot.logs_from(ctx.message.channel):
        if msg.author.id == '383804325077581834':
            msgs.append(msg)
        await bot.delete_messages(msgs)
```

The command you tried using needed a number parameter which would delete that number of messages from the channel.
The logs_from function will delete all messages from that channel if the limit is not passed into it.

EDIT: Forgot to remove number, whoops.

Comment: Thanks. But now I'm getting the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment`

Comment: The number isn't needed if you want to delete all messages so you can get rid of that line.